# Accumulated value sum with Arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum

I have a row of values `B2:F2` I want to `SUM` like i did in `B3:F3` but with the use of `Arrayformula`.

formulas in row `3` with locked `$B` column:

| **Month** | **Jan** | **Feb** | **Mar** | **Apr** | **May** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | 15,106 | 15,559 | 10,875 | 21,679 | 18,118 |
| Simple Cell formula | `=SUM($B2:B2)` | `=SUM($B2:C2)` | `=SUM($B2:D2)` | `=SUM($B2:E2)` | `=SUM($B2:F2)` |

---

**Progress**: I tried this formula but it outputs the `SUM` of the entire range `B2:F2` at once in the entire range `B4:F4`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:F2="",,SUM(B2:$F2)))
```

| **Month** | **Jan** | **Feb** | **Mar** | **Apr** | **May** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | 15,106 | 15,559 | 10,875 | 21,679 | 18,118 |
| Progress | `=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:F2="",,SUM(B2:$F2)))` | 81,336 | 81,336 | 81,336 | 81,336 |

---

What is the best formula to get the same result in `B3:F3` **but using `Arrayformula`?**
[***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdC4QTuJaYzK_xf1rGATLINBXJpJKB4jTkjRRfFXzHI/copy) of the example sheet.

[image]

### Update

When tring to roll forward i discoverd the case when the value row cell are empty, like this in column `J`, *if possible address this case in the answer*

[image]

Comment: I think you want to add more rows to your example range for summation

Comment: Hi @Argyll, I need the accumulated value of a single row `B2:F2` outputed using an Array based function / formula.

Comment: Hey everyone. I modified the original example sheet by adding my test and remarks. Look at [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdC4QTuJaYzK_xf1rGATLINBXJpJKB4jTkjRRfFXzHI/edit#gid=2074816165&range=A1).

Comment: Editing [@idfurw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357317/19529694) - [Edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73357317/timeline#history_c6102ee7-43a2-4e6c-98c8-9d7dc8ed1046) From `=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:2="",,SUMIF(COLUMN(B2:2),"<="&COLUMN(B2:2),B2:2)))
` to `=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="",,SUMIF(COLUMN(B2:2),"<="&COLUMN(B2:2),B2:2)))`  [See](https://i.imgur.com/NA5KBZ7.png) Produced the best result so far.

Comment: Conclusions for future visitors: [@idfurw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357317/19529694) is the simplist sloution using `SUMIF` but `IF(B1:1="",,` instead of `IF(B2:2="",,` , and [Player0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73361961/19529694) is the best option without `SUMIF` function, Dynamic and Computationally efficient. [See img](https://i.imgur.com/TOMHb2D.png) - and  [OP tests sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdC4QTuJaYzK_xf1rGATLINBXJpJKB4jTkjRRfFXzHI/edit#gid=2074816165&range=A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to calculate cumulative sum:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="",,SUMIF(COLUMN(B2:2),"<="&COLUMN(B2:2),B2:2)))
```

Comment: Hi @idfurw your formula worked great, but i discoverd when rolling forward if there is an empty cell for [**example**](https://i.imgur.com/KlRiUJG.png) in column `I` the output is empty `""`, and if used in chart is interrupted, can it be done when even if some cells are empty?

Comment: Sorry, I have wrongly specified the range in the `IF` statement, it should be `B1:1` instead of `B2:2`.

Answer (score 2):

standard transposed running total fx will do:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(5)<=SEQUENCE(1, 5))*
 FLATTEN(B2:F2)), SEQUENCE(5, 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

---

fully dynamic and maximally lightweight:

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:2="",,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 SEQUENCE(   MAX(COLUMN(C2:2)*(C2:2<>""))-COLUMN(C2)+1)<=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(COLUMN(C2:2)*(C2:2<>""))-COLUMN(C2)+1))*
 FLATTEN(INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(2, MAX(COLUMN(C2:2)*(C2:2<>"")))))), 
 SEQUENCE(   MAX(COLUMN(C2:2)*(C2:2<>""))-COLUMN(C2)+1, 1, 1, 0)))))
```

Comment: the Good thing it refrence's the range `C2:G2` once, but limited due to hard coded ranges like `SEQUENCE(5)` when end refrence dropped produces an **Error** [See this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdC4QTuJaYzK_xf1rGATLINBXJpJKB4jTkjRRfFXzHI/edit#gid=2074816165&range=C15)...

Comment: ...but when tring to make them dynamic this is what i did so far `=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(MAX(COUNTA(C1:1)))<=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(COUNTA(C1:1))))*
 TRANSPOSE( ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(C2:2),COUNTA(C1:1),1))), SEQUENCE(MAX(COUNTA(C1:1)), 1, 1, 0))))` [See this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DdC4QTuJaYzK_xf1rGATLINBXJpJKB4jTkjRRfFXzHI/edit#gid=2074816165&range=H16:J16)

Comment: @Osm see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qe94.png and also for examples on how to make range dynamic and lightweight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435313/arrayformula-of-average-on-infinite-truly-dynamic-range-in-google-sheets

Comment: Thanks for the update, changing =INDEX(IF(C2:2="",, to =INDEX(IF(C1:1="",, produces the desired output using your approach [see this](https://i.imgur.com/2cF5JKS.png).

Answer (score 0):

```
=arrayformula(mmult(if(isblank(B2:F2),0,B2:F2),if(column(B2:F2)>=transpose(column(B2:F2)),1,0)))
```

can produce a running sum in a row vector and can accommodate empty entries in the input range.

If you want to auto detect the number of columns in the input range, you can

1. replace `B2:F2` with `array_constrain(B2:2,1,max(arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:2),,column(B2:2))))-1)` and
2. replace `column(B2:F2)` with `array_constrain(column(B2:2),1,max(arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:2),,column(B2:2))))-1)`

which is to say, cut the range leaving the number of rows that is the max column index of occupied cells in our range; minus 1 because we started with column 2.

(Also, as long as there is one `arrayformula` wrapping the whole formula, you can omit them in the nested inputs, as long as you preserve the `()` brackets.)

Nonetheless, there would be a (computational) efficiency concern.

In order to centralize the formula, in the above solution, we first created a filter for each desired entry in our running sum vector, 1,0,0,... for 1st entry, 1,1,0,... for 2nd entry, 1,1,1,0,... for 3rd, etc. And then, effectly, we apply a `sum(filter(...))` via multiply by 1 or 0 using `mmult`. The array creation costs extra. The multiplication costs extra. And compared to iterated formulas that mutates cell by cell, we are not saving the multiply by 0 parts.

It may not end up being more than double or triple the runtime compared to iterated formulas. And you can experiment case by case. Small scale application is always fine. But for larger datasets, computational efficiency is something to keep in mind whenever we introduce extra computational steps, and potentially squaring the original amount when using `mmult` solutions.

Comment: Hi @Argyll thanks for your insight, I tested  `=mmult(sequence(1,rows(B2:2),1,0),B2:2)` Throws an error: [**Error**](https://i.imgur.com/cDy6nOy.png)
Function MMULT parameter 2 expects number values. But '' is a empty and cannot be coerced to a number, but your Approach led me to a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360616/19529694)

Comment: @Osm: Please see edits.

Comment: @Osm: I did write an `mmult` answer because originally I thought you wanted sums of columns. For simple running sums, it's best to find alternatives that are more computational efficient. And perhaps the fastest is cell-by-cell formulas.

Comment: Yes, of course, I saw all the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73359664/timeline). Computational efficiency in the case of a financial statement isn't a big deal. Using the `mmult` function is a good different approach to consider, thanks.